# React component is not receiving props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, babeljs

I'm trying to pass some parameters to my component from the React Router, but for some reason, the parameters are no longer present once the component is rendered.

Here is my code:

Router:

```
var routes = (
    <Route handler={require('components/forum-app')}>
        <DefaultRoute       handler={require('components/post-list')}/>
        <Route name='posts' handler={require('components/post-list')}/>
        <Route name='post'  handler={require('components/post')}        path='/post/:postId'/>
    </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function(Handler, options) {
    React.render(<Handler {...options}/>, document.body);
});
```

Post Component:

```
var Post = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

When I visit the route `#/post/post-1`, the post render method prints an empty object. I have checked and made sure the `options` variable in the `Router.run` callback has properties.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Post` class is nested in `forum-app` class. Therefore you should also pass properties from your `forum-app` class to its nested components:

```
<Router.RouteHandler {...this.props}/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I didn't notice this.